# How to get results of this particular "query"

Tags: sql, sqlite

**NOTE: I accidentally put another question's sentence in here (massive apologies on my part), I have updated this post as of Wednesday 14th March at 23:21pm with the correct question.**

I have spent a few hours trying to figure out this question without anyone's help but have realised I have wasted too much productive time and should've asked someone sooner. I had a decent crack at this and have come so close but cannot get the final solution I need. What I am supposed to get is:

> For all cases where the same reviewer rated the same movie twice and
>   gave it a higher rating the second time, return the reviewer's name
>   and the title of the movie.

This is the query I managed to get here:

```
SELECT reviewer.name, movie.title, rating.stars  
FROM (reviewer JOIN rating ON reviewer.rid = rating.rid)  
JOIN movie ON movie.mid = rating.mid  
GROUP BY reviewer.name 
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2  
ORDER BY reviewer.name DESC
```

(I have a feeling there is a missing WHERE clause from the above query, but am not sure where to place it)

(From what I have learned, RIGHT and FULL OUTER JOINs are not currently supported in SQLite)

And here are the tables and data (in pictures)...

[image: Movie]

[image: Reviewer]

[image: Rating]

... And the DB code...

```
/* Delete the tables if they already exist */
drop table if exists Movie;
drop table if exists Reviewer;
drop table if exists Rating;

/* Create the schema for our tables */
create table Movie(mID int, title text, year int, director text);
create table Reviewer(rID int, name text);
create table Rating(rID int, mID int, stars int, ratingDate date);

/* Populate the tables with our data */
insert into Movie values(101, 'Gone with the Wind', 1939, 'Victor Fleming');
insert into Movie values(102, 'Star Wars', 1977, 'George Lucas');
insert into Movie values(103, 'The Sound of Music', 1965, 'Robert Wise');
insert into Movie values(104, 'E.T.', 1982, 'Steven Spielberg');
insert into Movie values(105, 'Titanic', 1997, 'James Cameron');
insert into Movie values(106, 'Snow White', 1937, null);
insert into Movie values(107, 'Avatar', 2009, 'James Cameron');
insert into Movie values(108, 'Raiders of the Lost Ark', 1981, 'Steven Spielberg');

insert into Reviewer values(201, 'Sarah Martinez');
insert into Reviewer values(202, 'Daniel Lewis');
insert into Reviewer values(203, 'Brittany Harris');
insert into Reviewer values(204, 'Mike Anderson');
insert into Reviewer values(205, 'Chris Jackson');
insert into Reviewer values(206, 'Elizabeth Thomas');
insert into Reviewer values(207, 'James Cameron');
insert into Reviewer values(208, 'Ashley White');

insert into Rating values(201, 101, 2, '2011-01-22');
insert into Rating values(201, 101, 4, '2011-01-27');
insert into Rating values(202, 106, 4, null);
insert into Rating values(203, 103, 2, '2011-01-20');
insert into Rating values(203, 108, 4, '2011-01-12');
insert into Rating values(203, 108, 2, '2011-01-30');
insert into Rating values(204, 101, 3, '2011-01-09');
insert into Rating values(205, 103, 3, '2011-01-27');
insert into Rating values(205, 104, 2, '2011-01-22');
insert into Rating values(205, 108, 4, null);
insert into Rating values(206, 107, 3, '2011-01-15');
insert into Rating values(206, 106, 5, '2011-01-19');
insert into Rating values(207, 107, 5, '2011-01-20');
insert into Rating values(208, 104, 3, '2011-01-02');
```

I have another relatively similar question like this, but if I get some help on this one I should be able to apply the patterns and techniques from this one to the next one.

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have added an inner join with derived table that returns maximum stars per movie. Because of inner join between movies and ratings only movies with ratings will be retrieved. Join it back to main query to get maximum stars per movie.

Note: you stated that you wish to order by movie title but your query orders by reviewer.

```
SELECT reviewer.name, movie.title, rating.stars, maxStarsPerMovie.MaxStars
FROM (reviewer JOIN rating ON reviewer.rid = rating.rid)  
JOIN movie ON movie.mid = rating.mid  
join
(
   select movie.mid, max(rating.stars) MaxStars
   from movie
   inner join rating
      on movie.mid = rating.mid
   group by movie.mid
) maxStarsPerMovie
on movie.mid = maxStarsPerMovie.mid
ORDER BY reviewer.name DESC
```

EDIT: requiremets changed. This query will return list of reviewers who changed their opinion at later date in favor of the movie. It does so by joining ratings for the second time adding two filters on stars and date to join.

```
SELECT reviewer.name, movie.title, rating.ratingDate, rating.stars,
       newRating.ratingDate newRatingDate, newRating.Stars newRatingStars
FROM (reviewer JOIN rating ON reviewer.rid = rating.rid)  
JOIN movie ON movie.mid = rating.mid 
inner join rating newRating
     on newRating.mid = movie.mid
        and newRating.rid = reviewer.rid
        and newRating.ratingdate > rating.ratingdate
        and newRating.stars > rating.stars
ORDER BY reviewer.name, movie.title
```

Comment: Cheers for the answer, although this was for another question (I accidentally posted the wrong question originally, and have updated this post with the correct question). Your feedback will be useful for a couple other questions though :)

Answer (score 2):

From the description of the requirement:

> Return the movie title and number of stars (sorted by movie title) For each movie that has at least one rating, and find the highest number of stars that movie received.

The reviewer details do not appear to be required - only the Movie and the maximum stars.

Therefore, I suggest:

```
SELECT movie.mid, MAX(movie.title) as title, MAX(rating.stars) as max_stars
FROM rating 
JOIN movie ON movie.mid = rating.mid  
GROUP BY movie.mid 
ORDER BY 2, 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback :). I can say the same for you as I did for "Nikola Markovinović". Apologies for the confusion, although both of your feedback will help me out alot :).

Answer (score 0):

You were probably doing this for Stanford's SQL mini-course, as I just did. Here's what I got for my answer (I had no experience with SQL prior to watching the lectures, so hopefully this isn't too terrible):

Start with a query that finds each rID for a reviewer who rated a movie twice and gave it a higher score the second time:

```
 select R1.rID from Rating R1, Rating R2 where R1.mID = R2.mID and R1.rID = R2.rID
        and R1.ratingDate < R2.ratingDate and R2.stars > R1.stars;
```

think of R1 as the first rating of a particular movie by a particular reviewer, and R2 as the second.
We need to be talking about 2 reviews of the same movie by the same person, hence R1.mID = R2.mID and R1.rID = R2.rID. Next, to make sure that R1 was indeed first, chronologically, we set R1.ratingDate < R2.ratingDate, and to make sure that R2 was indeed given a greater score, we set R2.stars > R1.stars.

You can check to see that this gives us rID 201, which is the correct answer (can verify by checking the data). Now we need to display the movie reviewer name and title instead of the rID.

I did this by doing the cross product of all 3 relations (I suppose using joins would be cleaner?), removing duplicates and using the query listed above as a where clause subquery:

```
 select distinct name, title
 from Movie, Reviewer, Rating
 where Movie.mID = Rating.mID and Reviewer.rID = Rating.rID and Rating.rID in (select R1.rID from          
 Rating R1, Rating R2 where R1.mID =R2.mID and R1.rID = R2.rID and R1.ratingDate < R2.ratingDate
 and R2.stars > R1.stars);
```

In the where clause I just made the cross products into natural joins by setting the respective mIDs and rIDs equal, and made sure that the rIDs (called Rating.rID for disambiguation) were determined by the initial query that I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a Self Join in subquery to identify the reviewer and then use the result to get name of reviewer and movie title.

```
SELECT name, title FROM Reviewer R join (SELECT Ra.mID as mID, Ra.rID as rID FROM Rating Ra JOIN Rating Rb ON Ra.mID=Rb.mID WHERE Ra.rID=Rb.rID  AND Ra.ratingDate<Rb.ratingDate AND Ra.stars<Rb.stars) AS Tmp ON R.rID=Tmp.rID JOIN Movie M ON M.mID=Tmp.mID
```